# What does "lock time" mean?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, terminology, locktime

I got a transaction that is still not confirmed for about one week, and I can see a field called "Lock Time" that says:

Lock Time Block: 419382
https://blockchain.info/en/tx/ea445ae61c2906d43f8f8d73cfef2caefe3d63ae504da31a6a829cc35527faf6

What does that mean and how long do I have to wait until my transaction gets confirmed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A specified [locktime](https://bitcoin.org/en/transactions-guide#locktime-and-sequence-number) indicates that the transaction is only valid after a given blockheight.

Since the locktime field indicated is `419382` and currently the latest blockheight as of 12th July 2016 1108 (AEST) is `420352` the transaction is now valid and can be included in a block by any miner that chooses to do so.

Comment: This is incorrect. The nLockTime field (for height based logic) gives the largest height that cannot include the transaction.

Comment: If i changed it to "A specified locktime indicates that the transaction is only valid **after** a given blockheight", is that correct?

Comment: In that sense, a transaction with `"locktime": 3983071408` maybe not "unlock" in our lifetime!?! xref: the `coinbase` transaction of the block with height `714460`.

Answer (score 3):

Lock Time refers to at which block height the transaction can be included by a miner. In this case 419382 has well passed, so it can be included in any block at this point.  Your transaction is currently not confirmed since you have 5 inputs, and it was sent with zero fee. It may take a little while.  Not sure where you are coming up with the 1 week part, this transaction was created today.

Comment: I'm guessing the user sent the transaction a second time after 419382, since otherwise nodes would not relay it.  That's why the "Received Time" on blockchain.info is 7/11/2016.

Answer (score 0):

### Definition

Part of a transaction which indicates the earliest time or earliest block when that transaction may be added to the block chain.

[Bitcoin.org glossary](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/locktime)